# Is there any way to see the number of cards in a Trello board?

Tags: trello, trello-boards, project-management

Aside from physically counting them, is there any way to know the number of cards on a Trello board?

I did a search and I found that it's possible to see the number of cards in a list by turning on filtering, but again I have to add up these numbers which is fine for a few lists but not great for a large board.

I have a board where I think it would be handy for general business intelligence to monitor fluctuation in the number of cards, so ideally I'd even like a piece of software to show a weekly graph plot of how many active cards were on a board ... but I'd settle for just knowing how many were there without having to add up the individual list totals. **Does this exist?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am hoping you use Chrome as there is a great Extension that does exactly this:

- [Original Card Counter for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/original-card-counter-for/ggamggchfpnmhmkeicjgpedgjcllcefp?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [List Limits](https://trello.com/power-ups/5c2462c384ab8949b1724a20/list-limits) extension, it will show as ACTUAL_NUMBER / MAX (you have to set the MAX for each column).

[image]